# How to add to pytorch tensor at indices?

Tags: pytorch

I have to admit, I'm a bit confused by the scatter* and index* operations - I'm not sure any of them do exactly what I'm looking for, which is very simple:

Given some 2-D tensor

```
z = tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1., 1.],
            [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

And a list (or tensor?) of 2-d indexes:

```
inds = tensor([[0, 0],
               [1, 1],
               [1, 2]])
```

I want to add a scalar to z at those indexes (and do it efficiently):

```
znew = z.something_add(inds, 3)
->
znew = tensor([[4., 1., 1., 1.],
               [1., 4., 4., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

If I have to I can make that scalar a tensor of whatever shape (where all elements = 3), but I'd rather not...

Comment: In case anybody comes here to find a solution for overlapping indices, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584479/3337089

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must provide two lists to your indexing. The first having the row positions and the second the column positions. In your example, it would be:

```
z[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]] += 3
```

torch.Tensor indexing follows Numpy. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing for more details.

Comment: I'm accepting yours because it works and you were first. I still have concerns though - will this be efficient? If both z and inds are gpu-resident tensors, can this all be done on the gpu? It seems like there should be some method on tensor that can do this, and do it efficiently...

Comment: I think it's supposed to be efficient, even if you are passing CPU lists. I'm not sure for huge indices arrays though. If you tensor is very big but you only care about some of the components, try [`torch.sparse`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html).

Answer (score 1):

This code achieves what you want:

```py
z_new = z.clone() # copy the tensor
z_new[inds[:, 0], inds[:, 1]] += 3 # modify selected indices of new tensor
```

In PyTorch, you can index each axis of a tensor with another tensor.