# Add a index selected tensor to another tensor with overlapping indices in pytorch

Tags: numpy, pytorch

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65038757/3337089). I want to do the exactly same thing in pytorch. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

```
import torch
image = torch.tensor([[246,  50, 101], [116,   1, 113], [187, 110,  64]])
iy = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2]])
ix = torch.tensor([[0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
warped_image = torch.zeros(size=image.shape)
```

I need something like `torch.add.at(warped_image, (iy, ix), image)` that gives the output as

```
[[  0.   0.  51.]
 [246. 116.   0.]
 [300. 211.  64.]]
```

Note that the indices at `(0,1)` and `(1,1)` point to the same location `(0,2)`. So, I want `warped_image[0,2] = image[0,1] + image[1,1] = 51`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`torch.Tensor.index_put_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.index_put_) with the `accumulate` argument set to `True`:

```
>>> warped_image = torch.zeros_like(image)

>>> warped_image.index_put_((iy, ix), image, accumulate=True)
tensor([[  0,   0,  51],
        [246, 116,   0],
        [300, 211,  64]])
```

Or, using the out-place version `torch.index_put`:

```
>>> torch.index_put(torch.zeros_like(image), (iy, ix), image, accumulate=True)
tensor([[  0,   0,  51],
        [246, 116,   0],
        [300, 211,  64]])
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I hope this allows the gradients to flow.

Comment: Yes! If you set `requires_grad` to `True` on `image`, then `warped_image` will turn out with a `grad_fn` (used to backpropagate) set to `<IndexPutBackward>`.

Comment: I need the gradients to flow through the indices as well, but I'm getting an error for that. Any idea how to solve it or any workarounds? I've asked a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66973502/3337089)

Comment: @NagabhushanSN I don't think you can pass a gradient through the indices, as those are discrete and non-differentiable

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. And it turned out that that wasn't needed after all.