# pytorch index_put_ gives RuntimeError: the derivative for 'indices' is not implemented

Tags: pytorch, autograd

This is follow up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65584330/3337089). I tried using `index_put_` as suggested in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584479/3337089), however I'm getting the following error

```
RuntimeError: the derivative for 'indices' is not implemented
```

I want to backpropagate the error gradients through the indices and hence I can't `detach()` it. Is there any way possible to achieve this?

Example:

```
import torch
image = torch.tensor([[246,  50, 101], [116,   1, 113], [187, 110,  64]])
iy = torch.tensor([[1, 0, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2]])
ix = torch.tensor([[0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0], [0, 1, 2]])
warped_image = torch.zeros(size=image.shape)
warped_image.index_put_((iy, ix), image, accumulate=True)
```