# PyTorch add to tensor at indices with degenerate indices

Tags: python, pytorch

This question may be seen as an extension to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012586/how-to-add-to-pytorch-tensor-at-indices).

I have two 1D tensors, `counts` and `idx`. Counts is length 20 and stores the occurrences of events that fall into 1 of 20 bins. `idx` is very long, and each entry is an integer which corresponds to the occurrence of 1 of the 20 events, and each event can occur multiple times. I'd like a vectorized or very fast way to add the number of times event `i` occurred in `idx` to the `i`'th bucket in `counts`. Furthermore, it would be ideal if the solution was compatible with operation on batches of `count`'s and `idx`'s during a training loop.

My first thought was to simply use this strategy of indexing `counts` with `idx`:

```
counts = torch.zeros(5)

idx = torch.tensor([1,1,1,2,3])

counts[idx] += 1
```

But it did not work, with counts ending at

```
tensor([0., 1., 1., 1., 0.])
```

instead of the desired

```
tensor([0., 3., 1., 1., 0.])
```

What's the fastest way I can do this? My next best guess is

```
for i in range(20):
   counts[i] += idx[idx == i].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following proposal implemented with the **bincount** function which counts the frequency of each value in tensor of **non-negative** ints (The only constraint).

```
import torch

EVENT_TYPES = 20
counts = torch.zeros(EVENT_TYPES)
events = torch.tensor([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 9])
batch_counts = torch.bincount(events, minlength=EVENT_TYPES)

print(counts + batch_counts)
```

Result:

`tensor([0., 3., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0.])`

You can evaluate that for every batch being only in torch tensor environment. You control the number of event types using the minlength argument in the bincount function. In this case 20 as you described in the problem.